# ListView Selection Lost after ItemMove

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I got a ListView which **ItemsSource** is bound to a **CollectionViewSource** which Source is a **ObservableCollection** the Items are sorted by **DateTime**.

At runtime the **DateTime** of an item could change, so I move that item in the **ObservableCollection** to an appropriate index. Everytime I do so the ListView will lose the selection if the moved item is selected. Also it seems that the ListView is completly reset. How to avoid this behaviour? I want the ListView to keep the Item selected!

Quick reselection of the item is no Option because there is another View associated to the item selection that will load data and so on...

Download of Demo project: [CLICK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_109B1czjk1MklrX1cybnhvWkk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: it would be much better if you can past some code into your question instead of putting a link to your project

Comment: @El Marchewko If you move the item from your collection,that will immediately affect t he UI since you are using an observable collection.

Comment: Sure, but why is it resetting all items? That looks like an error... Also i cant unterstand why it looses the selection. That is not my expected behaviour, since ObservableCollection can notify the view explicit about a item Move.

Comment: Are to binding to the original ObservableCollection or a sorted version of it?